# Double cascading value relation in QGIS attribute form

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-form

I run a PostgreSQL database using QGIS as a frontend. I have a table in which I store archaeological finds related to sites. The finds-table has no geometry and just stores date. To be able to query my data in different ways, I have three fields to describe the nature of these finds, which are however interdependent (material,group,type). E.g. material=Pottery, group=Vessel, type=Vipperow or material=Iron, group=Sword, type=A27. I have used the *value relation widget* to create cascading input forms, that should allow only object types from groups that can be e.g. iron to displayed, when I set material to iron and only types of swords, when I set group to sword.

These two relations look like that in the editor:
[image: Relationship between group and material]

[image: Relationship between material and type]

This worked fine as long as I only had one relation between material and group, now I entered the second one between group and type and this appears not to work. I created relation tables for both, which both look quite alike (see below) and use the same filters. However, the material-group relation works but the group-type relation does not. It shows certain possible input option but always sets the same in any case. It is also not possible to enter certain option, which are int the tables. The table I use for the relationships are.

Table with the relationship material to group = **finds_groups**
[image: Relation table material to group]

Table with the relationship group to type = **finds_types**
[image: Relation table group to type]

Is it possible to run double cascading value relations in QGIS, or is there some error in my settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the *Value Relation* widget, the *Value column* is for the values shwon in the list, and the *Key column* is for the values to be stored in the table in which the widget is applied.

You are storing *finds_groups.material* values in the *finds.group* field.
That is why you cannot match *finds.group* values in the *finds.type* field filter expression widget.

You need to use *group* column as Key and Value columns in the *finds.group* field widget.
In that way, the list will show *finds_groups.group* values that match the filter expression (those rows for which *finds_groups.material* value is equal to the current *finds.material* value), and store the choosen *group* value, in the *finds.group* field.

Then, use *type* as Key and Value columns in the *finds.type* widget.
In that way, the list will show *finds_groups.type* values that match the filter expression (those rows for which *finds_type.group* value is equal to the current *finds.group* value), and store the choosen *type* value, in the *finds.type* field.

Comment: I don't really get why, but this works. As I understood it from this introduction (https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-3-2-drive-down-lists-aka-value-relation-widget) it should have worked the way I did it, but apparently there is an error in my reasoning.

Comment: @C.-F.Vintar, in that introduction, they was storing _id_ of the type in the _wells.type_ field, and then filtering _tableb.fk_ values that match the _wells.type_ current value in the _wells.subtype_ widget. You was storing material values in your _group_ field (I don't know the name of your table beacuse you clip the title in layer properties screenshot), and then trying to filter groups with that material value stored. All you need to know is that the _Key column_ parmeter of the _Value Relation_ widget is the value to be stored in the table.